# Windows 10 Setup on Pi Zero not working

Tags: boot, ssh, pi-zero, boot-issues, windows

I'm trying to set up a Raspberry Pi Zero (*not* a Zero W) with Raspberry Pi OS Lite (32-bit), headless through USB. I'm not great with computers (using CMD is a real headscratcher for me), to put this in perspective, and was hoping to use this Pi to boot up and run a single .exe game file (basically a self-contained game on the Pi itself). The general process I've been following goes like this:

- Format microSD using Raspberry Pi Imager v1.4
- add `dtoverlay=dwc2` to `config.txt` and `modules-load=dwc2,g_ether` to cmdline.txt
- add SSH as an empty text file
- insert microSD into Pi Zero and plug in USB cable to USB (not power) port on Pi Zero. Wait 2 minutes for full bootup.
- Open CMD and enter `ssh` pi@raspberrypi.local.

This is where I encounter my error - no matter what I do, the Pi is never found. I've tried two different SD cards (moved off of 64GB thinking EXFAT might be causing problems instead of the standard SDFAT), with the same results.

Things I noticed that should be going right:

- The green LED on the Pi Zero appears to behave normally - it blinks for about a minute before steady output.
- SSH file is deleted upon opening microSD card after failed `ssh` connection. I've been recreating it for each test, but I'm not sure this is necessary.

Things I noticed that might be causing issues:

- The USB cable is marked as a micro USB cable (trident logo), but may not be a data cable. I'm not quite sure how to test this. Unfortunately, my phone is USB-C.
- config.txt has some extra lines compared to the walkthroughs I've been perusing, which are below:

```
[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
```

Deleting these has no effect. I'm probably doing something very obviously wrong, but I have no way of telling what it is and none of the guides I've found have any advice if the SSH step is failed. I've also tried using `PuTTY` and installing Bonjour, neither of which seems to have accomplished anything. I'd really like to get this on VNC Viewer eventually, but if I can't pass the SSH, that's a long way off.

Comment: Are you really typing `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`? If so, have you defined where `raspberrypi.local` is located on your network?

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha - zeroconf/bonjour/avahi/mdns (it has many names) will take care of that - OP is doing the right thing

Comment: Does a new network device appear in windows device manager (network adapters) when you plug the pi in? Which USB connector on the pi are you using?

Comment: @JaromandaX No, it does not. As far as I can tell (which is admittedly not much), this is a micro-USB-B cable, and has the trident logo, so it should transfer data. Unfortunately, I don't have any other devices to test it with.

Comment: which usb port are you using on the pi?

Comment: The one marked USB, closest to the center.

Comment: SOLVED - it was the USB cable. Found one that explicitly advertised itself as a data cable and the Pi patched through after about a minute's wait.